# Writing CipherParameters to file system

Tags: java, security, rsa, bouncycastle, java-io

Is there any way that we can write this public, private key generated through RSAKeyPairGenerator to file system (I know this is not a good idea but I need to check whether this can be done)?

RSAKeyPairGenerator will result in CipherParameters and I am using bouncy castle security provide for java.

Code is as follows to get my keys.

```
    RSAKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();

    keyPairGenerator.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(new BigInteger(
            "10001", 16), new SecureRandom(), 1024, 80));

    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    CipherParameters pubKey = keys.getPublic();
    CipherParameters privKey = keys.getPrivate();
```

Comment: CipherParameter is not serializable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the parameters up to the actual type (print out `privKey.getClass().getName()` to find out what it is). The RSA private key will be a type of `RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters`. Once you've got that you can simply retrieve the `BigInteger`'s that make up to private key. Those should be serializable. If you want to encode it in PKCS#8/PKCS#1 then you should create a JCE compatible `RSACrtPrivateKey` instance and call `getEncoded()`.